# ld: 9 duplicate symbols clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) error while building reactnative ios app

Tags: xcode, react-native, linker-errors

I encountered this error while building my React Native(0.66.4) app on iOS using Xcode 15.1.

I attempted to resolve the issue by downgrading Xcode to version 14.3.1

```
duplicate symbol 'folly::detail::str_to_bool(folly::Range<char const*>*)' in:

    /Users/hamzabakaran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-ctpnuulbuipfykbyqdihvziwoxdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a(Conv.o)

    /Users/hamzabakaran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-ctpnuulbuipfykbyqdihvziwoxdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly/libRCT-Folly.a(Conv.o)

duplicate symbol 'folly::makeConversionError(folly::ConversionCode, folly::Range<char const*>)' in:

    /Users/hamzabakaran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-ctpnuulbuipfykbyqdihvziwoxdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a(Conv.o)

    /Users/hamzabakaran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-ctpnuulbuipfykbyqdihvziwoxdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly/libRCT-Folly.a(Conv.o)

duplicate symbol 'folly::exception_wrapper::from_exception_ptr(std::exception_ptr&&)' in:

    /Users/hamzabakaran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-ctpnuulbuipfykbyqdihvziwoxdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)

    /Users/hamzabakaran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-ctpnuulbuipfykbyqdihvziwoxdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly/libRCT-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)

duplicate symbol 'folly::exception_wrapper::from_exception_ptr(std::exception_ptr const&)' in:

    /Users/hamzabakaran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-ctpnuulbuipfykbyqdihvziwoxdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)

    /Users/hamzabakaran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-ctpnuulbuipfykbyqdihvziwoxdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly/libRCT-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)

duplicate symbol 'folly::exception_wrapper::onNoExceptionError(char const*)' in:

    /Users/hamzabakaran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-ctpnuulbuipfykbyqdihvziwoxdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)

    /Users/hamzabakaran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-ctpnuulbuipfykbyqdihvziwoxdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly/libRCT-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)

duplicate symbol 'folly::exceptionStr(folly::exception_wrapper const&)' in:

    /Users/hamzabakaran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-ctpnuulbuipfykbyqdihvziwoxdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)

    /Users/hamzabakaran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-ctpnuulbuipfykbyqdihvziwoxdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly/libRCT-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)

duplicate symbol 'folly::exception_wrapper::uninit_' in:

    /Users/hamzabakaran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-ctpnuulbuipfykbyqdihvziwoxdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)

    /Users/hamzabakaran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-ctpnuulbuipfykbyqdihvziwoxdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly/libRCT-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)

duplicate symbol 'folly::exception_wrapper::ExceptionPtr::ops_' in:

    /Users/hamzabakaran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-ctpnuulbuipfykbyqdihvziwoxdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)

    /Users/hamzabakaran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-ctpnuulbuipfykbyqdihvziwoxdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly/libRCT-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)

duplicate symbol 'folly::exception_wrapper::SharedPtr::ops_' in:

    /Users/hamzabakaran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-ctpnuulbuipfykbyqdihvziwoxdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)

    /Users/hamzabakaran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-ctpnuulbuipfykbyqdihvziwoxdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly/libRCT-Folly.a(ExceptionWrapper.o)

ld: 9 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ld: 9 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

, but unfortunately, I still encountered the same error. Additionally, I tried the following steps to troubleshoot:

1.Cleaned the Xcode build folder.
2.Removed the Podfile.lock file.
3.Deleted the Pods folder.
4.Ran pod install to regenerate the Pods.
Despite these efforts, the error persists.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

Comment: Edit your question and list the duplicate symbols. Without the names of the duplicate symbols, no one can answer your question. Press Cmd-5 in Xcode to open the issue navigator to see a list of errors. If the symbol isn't there, press Cmd-9 to open the report navigator and access the build log to see what the duplicate symbols are. See the following article for screenshots: [Why Won't My Xcode Project Build?](https://www.swiftdevjournal.com/why-wont-my-xcode-project-build/).

Answer (score 0):

Change DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING = YES for debug in project.pbxproj. This helped me solve this error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).